# How to initialize my circuit with two random complex numbers?

Tags: qiskit, programming, textbook-and-exercises

Working through [Lab 3](https://learn.qiskit.org/course/ch-labs/lab-3-quantum-measurements) in the Qiskit text, I have been attempting to initialize my one qubit circuit with two random numbers.  My first attempt, as directed, is using `.initialize` function, but I keep getting an error:'Sum of amplitudes-squared does not equal one.'

My code

```
qc = QuantumCircuit(1)

#### your code goes here
#Create random initial state
SignChoice=[1,-1]
a=random.choice(SignChoice)*random.random()
b=random.choice(SignChoice)*random.random()
p=complex(a,b)
q=np.sqrt(1-p**2)
initial_state = [p,q]  # Define state |q_0>
qc.initialize(initial_state, 0) # Initialise the 0th qubit in the state `initial_state`
```

In attempting to fix this error I have used the code below to see my amplitudes and the sum of their squares and though I can see that rounding may sometimes be an issue, it does often result in exactly 1+0j, which leaves me wondering why it will not initialize!

```
print(p,q,p**2+q**2)
```

My second attempt will be with
`random_statevector`,
but I have not yet completed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it slightly different and then you will have no error.
Generate 4 random numbers instead of 2, and set `q` in the same way as `p`.
Then you can compute the `norm` of `p` and `q` using `np.linalg.norm()` method and set `initial_state` to be a list of `p` and `q` divided by the norm.

Here's the code fixed:

```
qc = QuantumCircuit(1)

#### your code goes here
#Create random initial state
SignChoice = [1,-1]

a=random.choice(SignChoice)*random.random()
b=random.choice(SignChoice)*random.random()
c=random.choice(SignChoice)*random.random()
d=random.choice(SignChoice)*random.random()

p=complex(a,b)
q=complex(c,d)
amplitudes = [p,q]
norm = np.linalg.norm(amplitudes)

initial_state = amplitudes/norm  # Define state |q_0>
qc.initialize(initial_state, 0) # Initialise the 0th qubit in the state `initial_state`
```

Comment: The norm!  I can't believe I missed that! Thanks!  What advantage is there in using save_statevector()? I found I did not need this part and am curious why you took this extra step? @Ohad

Comment: No need in save_statevector(). My bad. I'll delete that.